# Rules for intercepting attacks and protecting others

Tags: combat, anima-beyond-fantasy, defense

Both the Guardian Ars Magnus and Bodyguard combat module in Dominus Exxet imply that you can intercept an attack directed at other creatures, but I simply cannot find the rules that explain it. I have gone through the Corebook and GM's Toolkit several times but I have only seen the Push Aside maneuver and covering others with supernatural shields.

Can somebody please explain the rules for intercepting attacks and protecting others, or tell me where is it written?

Answer (score 2):

#### The rules for this do not exist, aside from the references you have already laid out.

I really really hope that another answer appears that proves me wrong, but I built a character who would have loved to use these rules, once upon a time, and couldn't find any better references. We ended up homebrewing a few techniques based off of Push Aside, but using different stats and with different upsides and downside. Block-based maneuvers were usually easier but risked health, while Dodge had less personal risk but was less likely to work.